# Azure notification hub broken all registered devices deleted

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Today something was wrong with my push notifications. I notice an error in my notification backend and no notification being sent to my apps.

So I got into azure portal and wasn't able to see this notification hub... so I panic. (and I'm still in panic)

I had more than 50k devices registered in this notification hub... so I dig a little more and found that this notification hub was in an "unhealthy state" whatever that means... I followed some steps, re-created it with the same name, copied and pasted the same Google cloud message API key... but at the end the **AZURE shared access key was a NEW ACCESS KEY** and all **my apps are now using another key** to register to this notification hub...

basically I CAN'T KEEP REGISTERING MY APPS IF I DONT UPGRADE THEM which seems to me really stupid... unless I upgrade them with this new endpoint (no way!)

my question is, is there any way to TELL AZURE which key I'm using in production?? this guys let me regenerate the key but they don't let me paste THE KEY THAT I AM ACTUALLY USING!! they are forcing me to change it which means to upgrade all my apps.

currently I have no devices being registered and my 50k devices seems to be lost!

anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Azure portal don't have option to provide your key but you can do it through programmatically (.Net SDK). Here is the sample code for this.

Install Nugget from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/

```
NamespaceManager manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("<Namespace connection string>");
NotificationHubDescription hubDescription = manager.GetNotificationHub("<hubName>");
hubDescription.SetDefaultAccessPasswords("old_fullAccessPassword ", "old_listenAccessPassword ");
manager.UpdateNotificationHub(hubDescription);
```

Thanks,
Sateesh